# R: how to use user-defined function on my data

Tags: r, dplyr

I am carrying out data analysis using R but have some problem with coding.
I create my own function for creating frequency table and apply it to variables in my data, but R shows error message.

Could anyone can give me any solution and why it did not work?

```
> str(diabetes)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   56632 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ ID       : chr  "A308059801" "A308059802" "A308120201" "A308120202" ...
 $ year     : num  2010 2010 2010 2010 2010 2010 2010 2010 2010 2010 ...
 $ region   : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sex      : num  1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ age      : num  61 54 33 33 4 65 59 54 49 18 ...
 $ edu      : chr  "3.000000" "2.000000" "3.000000" "4.000000" ...
 $ occp     : chr  "5.000000" "3.000000" "4.000000" "1.000000" ...
 $ marri_1  : 'labelled' num  1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Marriage Y/N"
 $ marri_2  : 'labelled' num  1 1 1 1 8 1 1 1 1 8 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Marriage status"
 $ tins     : 'labelled' num  10 20 10 10 10 20 20 10 10 10 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Insurance registration"
 $ D_1_1    : 'labelled' chr  "3.000000" "2.000000" "2.000000" "3.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Self-report health status"
 $ DI1_dg   : 'labelled' chr  "1.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "HBP diagnosis"
 $ DI1_pr   : 'labelled' chr  "1.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "HBP current status"
 $ DI1_pt   : 'labelled' chr  "1.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "HBP care"
 $ DE1_dg   : 'labelled' chr  "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Diabetes diagnosis"
 $ DE1_pr   : 'labelled' chr  "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Diabetes status"
 $ DE1_pt   : 'labelled' chr  "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Diabetes cure"
 $ HE_DMdg  : 'labelled' chr  "0.000000" "0.000000" "0.000000" "0.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Diabetes doctor diagnosis"
 $ HE_BMI   : 'labelled' chr  "26.177198" "22.807647" "26.562865" "20.863743" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "BMI"
 $ HE_DM    : 'labelled' chr  "2.000000" "3.000000" "1.000000" "1.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "With diagnosis(over 19 year-old)"
 $ LQ4_07   : 'labelled' chr  "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Barries for physical activity - diabetes"
 $ HE_DMfh1 : 'labelled' chr  "0.000000" "0.000000" "9.000000" "1.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Father with diagnosis"
 $ HE_DMfh2 : 'labelled' chr  "1.000000" "0.000000" "9.000000" "0.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Mother with diagnosis"
 $ HE_DMfh3 : 'labelled' chr  "0.000000" "0.000000" "9.000000" "0.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Sibling with diagnosis"
 $ HE_glu   : 'labelled' chr  "124.000000" "141.000000" "92.000000" "88.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Diabetes indicator - glucose level"
 $ BE5_1    : 'labelled' chr  "1.000000" "1.000000" "1.000000" "1.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Muscle training frequency"
 $ LQ4_04   : 'labelled' chr  "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Barriers for physical activity - Have heart disease"
 $ DF2_dg   : 'labelled' chr  "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" "8.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Diagnosed with depression"
 $ HE_IHDfh1: 'labelled' chr  "0.000000" "0.000000" "9.000000" "0.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Diagnosed with Ischaemic heart disease"
 $ HE_HP    : 'labelled' chr  "3.000000" "3.000000" "2.000000" "1.000000" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Hypertension Status (three levels)"


freq_table <- function (y) {
  d <-   select (y) %>% group_by (y) %>% summarise (n = n ()) %>% mutate (freq = n / sum (n))
}

lapply(diabetes$marri_1, freq_table)
```

Comment: 1. `str` will not help debug your problem. You might need to share `dput`.

2. Based on that `dput` show what output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select function is at the beginning of the pipe and needs at least two arguments, you can add the name of the dataframe to the argument function
Also, because y is stored in a variable you have to unquote it when using the `dplyr` verbs by adding `!!` before it.

```
library(tidyverse)
# add df as an argument and add it before the select
freq_table <- function (df,y) {
  d <-   df %>% select (!! y) %>% group_by (!! y) %>% summarise (n = n ()) %>% mutate (freq = n / sum (n))
}

freq_table(diabetes,"marri_1")
```

Or in a more simple way you can do

```
tab <- table(diabetes$marri_1)
tab <- as.data.frame(tab)
names(tab) <- c("marri_1","n")
tab$freq <- tab$n /sum(tab$n)
```

Is this what you were looking for ?

Comment: The first suggestion did not work. The second suggestion works very well. I may not have knowledge regarding data frame in R, but usually the code that you suggested should work (actually I tried the same code with your suggest before asking this question). Can your explain the reason why it really doesn't work?

Comment: its because of the quotation marks in y when you evaluate `freq_table`, I have updated my answer, `!!` unquotes y